# How to create gettable template type data sa class field?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++03

I have a:

```
template<class T, class E>
class Bla {
}
```

I want to make T accessable for other classes with something like:

```
Bla::TypeOfE
```

Is such thing possible in C++03 and how to do it?

Comment: No you can't do it in this way. You could perhaps make it work like `Bla<int, int>::TypeOfE`. What type do you want it to refer to in this case? The type is specific for each instance of the template class.

Answer (score 0):

Add in `public` section

```
typedef T TypeOfT;
```

Use it like

```
Bla<int, double>::TypeOfT value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
template<class T, class E>
class Bla {
 public:
     typedef E TypeOfE;
}
```